# Reading from serial but only take the newest data

Tags: c++, serial-port

I have a device sending sensor data to my computer. I'm writing a program with C++ that reads the data and process it. But assume my C++ program has a lot of work to do, so when it has time to read the data, the device might have already sent dozens of readings over the serial port.

If I simply read the data one line after another, my program would appear to be getting the lagged response because it's getting unprocessed old data. I'm not sure what's the best way to deal with this.

1. I can keep reading until I get to the last line of data. But which library has the function that returns whether there is any more data to read, so I can determine whether I'm reading the last one?
2. Or is there some function to just clean the FIFO buffer and wait for a new data? And which library can I use for that?

Comment: ooo multiple choice.  #2!

Comment: is there any library that has that function?

Comment: most of them should.  it's just flushing.

Comment: I didn't know it's called flushing.. thanks for the direction.

Comment: it seems that boost asio doesn't have the flush function. :(

Comment: 2. is not a good way because I have to wait for the next data.

Comment: Use `select` or `poll` or a higher-level library such as `libevent` that encapsulates them. See e.g. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Serial-Programming-HOWTO

Comment: Another method (may actually be preferable) is to run a separate reader thread and make it expose just the last read record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost ASIO is a good library and should fit your requirement. Check the documentation for [read_until](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html%20link)